# Horizontal placement of components in JSF

Tags: jsf

Should be simple but I couldn't find the answer, I would like to place components horizontally instead of vertically.

What I'm trying to achieve is a rich:toolbar with 2 or more rows. I've been trying to do that with a toolbar that has a panelgrid and two panelgroups like this:

```
<rich:toolbar...>
  <f:panelgrid columns="1"...>
    <f:panelgroup id="row1" .../>  <-- Should be horizontal placement
    <f:panelgroup id="row2" .../>  <-- Should be horizontal placement
  <f:panelgrid/>
<rich:toolbar/>
```

So how do I make the panelgroup layout horizontal (Or should I use something else?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably already know that JSF in webserver ends up as HTML in webbrowser. In HTML, there are several ways to place elements horizontally (eventually with help of CSS):

1. Group them in inline elements (like `<span>` or any element with `display: inline;`).
2. Group them in block elements (like `<div>` or any element with `display: block;`) **and** give them all a `float: left;`.

The JSF `<h:panelGrid>` renders a HTML `<table>` element wherein each child component is taken as a `<td>`. The `columns` attribute represents the max amount of `<td>` elements in a single `<tr>` (so that the `<h:panelGrid>` knows when to put a `</tr><tr>` in). The JSF `<h:panelGroup>` renders a `<span>` element.

To achieve way 1 with JSF, you just need to group them in separate `<h:panelGroup>` components.

```
<rich:toolbar ...>
    <h:panelgroup id="row1" ... />
    <h:panelgroup id="row2" ... />
</rich:toolbar>
```

Way 2 can be done the same way, but then with `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` instead and a `float: left;` in their CSS.

Comment: Great! Thanks for adding that educational part. I am self tutored on JSF and missing a lot of basics...